# Перенос строки MaterialUi

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Как убрать перенос слова на вторую строку?

```
<Box>
<Box>
<Box>

<Typography theme={theme} variant='h8' border="1px black" colors="tehs.main" maxWidth="200px" sx={{ position: 'absolute', left: '145px', top: '20px' }}>

       Добрый день

      </Typography>

</Box>
</Box>
</Box>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить свойство noWrap

```
<Typography noWrap theme={theme} variant='h8' border="1px black" colors="tehs.main" maxWidth="200px" sx={{ position: 'absolute', left: '145px', top: '20px' }}>
```